# Python how to get the domain of a cookie

Tags: python

I want to get the domain of the cookie from the HTTP response. Code is:

```
cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie() 
cookie.load(cookie_string) 
print 'cookie = ', cookie
```

this shows the cookie as

cookie= Set-Cookie: Cycle=MA==|MA==|MA==; Domain=.abc.xyz.net; expires=Tue, 05-Oct-2021 04:15:18 GMT; Path=/

I want to extract the domain from the above result.

I am trying

```
print cookie['Domain']
print cookie['Domain'].value
print cookie['Cycle']['Domain'].value
```

None of these work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
cookie['Cycle']['domain']    # lowercase domain !
```

Comment: cookie['session']['domain']  OR                              cookie['session']['Domain']  give an error                                     NameError: global name 'session' is not defined

Comment: @SUM: of course, 'session' was an example cookie name. It your case it's 'Cycle'. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank u. Get the same error.                                                                  print cookie[Cycle][domain]
NameError: global name 'domain' is not defined

Comment: You're right, lowercase is required. This is odd because the Python docs specifically say that cookie morsel keys are case-insensitive.